# In case of failed security authentication, IDispatchMessageInspector won't be triggered?

Tags: .net, wcf, wcf-security

I implement the IDispatchMessageInspector interface to log the raw request/response message. I apply it via the IEndpointBehavior interface. It works well in most secenarios. But I find the messages does not be logged any more when the authentication fail.(I use TransportWithMessageCredential in the basicHttpBinding). So I start to debug the WCF service and find the inspector doesn't be invoked. What happen to this case?

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: The most probable reason is that security is involved before your inspector.

Answer (score 1):

The authentication happens before processing any request, once authentication fails, the service won't process any request, of course, IDispatchMessageInspector won't be invoked.

And when the authentication happens, the client won't send any request to the service. If you do want to log the raw message, you may insert a custom BindingElement into the binding.

Comment: So if I want to log the raw message or change the response, for example, adding my own header, how can I do in this case? Is there other method like IDispatchMessageInspector to inject the channel stack? Thanks.

Comment: You can use this interface to add your custom header to the response but it requires that the authentication is passed. Think about this: if the authentication fails, it means the message is invalidate, why do you need to change the invalidate message? This article explains the extensions points of WCF in detail: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163302.aspx.